# How can one device determine whether another's Bluetooth is connected, using J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth

I am trying to connect two Bluetooth devices using J2ME. Both devices connect successfully and also transfer data very well. If one of the devices has its Bluetooth switched off, how can the other device know that the connection has been lost?

```
MIDP= 2.0  
cldc= 1.1
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this scenario to see what happens? I guess if you have an active connection with a device and it drops for whatever reason, some sort of `IOException` will be thrown on the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am currently developing a J2ME game that works over bluetooth,
and you could run into two different scenarios, the first being one of the devices falling out of range and failing to deliver data and that can be solved by forcing the communicating devices to send acknowledgments on receiving data, and checking for that every fixed period of time, the second scenario which resembles yours, will cause an Exception, probably an IOException which can be caught and dealt with.

harshad

Answer (score 0):

Hey Hi, You need to run one thread in J2ME application,this thread running after some period of time & this thread needs to check whether Bluetooth connection available for selected Bluetooth or not.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i am currently developing a J2ME game that works over bluetooth,
and you could run into two different scenarios, the first being one of the devices falling out
of range and failing to deliver data and that can be solved by forcing the communicating devices to send acknowledgments on receiving data, and checking for that every fixed period of time, the second scenario which resembles yours, will cause an Exception, probably an `IOException` which can be caught and dealt with.